# need help to change colour in cv2, with user input in tinker

Tags: python, opencv, colors, tuples, tinker

I have a list of colours:

```
    red = (50, 50, 255)
    blue = (255, 127, 0)
    dark_blue = (127, 20, 0)
    green = (127, 255, 0)
```

initially, I set output colour:

```
    line_colour = red
```

this works when drawing a line:

```
    cv2.line(img, (x3, y3), (x2, y2), line_colour, 5)
```

I expanded the program to get colour input from user, via tinker:

```
    colour_list = ['red', 'blue', 'dark blue', 'green',
           'light green', 'yellow', 'pink', 'black', 'white']
```

I am able to get the colour:

```
    line_clicked.get()
```

Need help to change the cv2.line(......) so that the line colour is drawn with the user colour choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put all your colors in a dictionary, with the name as a key, and the RGB as a value.

Something like:

```
color_dict = {'red': (50, 50, 255),
               'blue' : (255, 127, 0),
               'dark blue': (127, 20, 0)}  # etc...
```

Then if you have a color selected by the user:

```
selected_colour_name = line_clicked.get()
```

You can use the dictionary to get the RGB color and draw it:

```
line_colour = colour_dict[selected_colour_name]
cv2.line(img, (x3, y3), (x2, y2), line_colour, 5)
```